# How to determine the type of event flagged by <<ListBoxSelect>> in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am binding to ListBoxSelect and i want to implement a function which recognizes an alphabetical key-press and uses this to jump to the corresponding place in an alphabetically sorted list.

Is there a way to tell what type of event is flagged by ListBoxSelect? I see something in the documentation about getting event "keysym" but i dont know how to access this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to tell what type of event is flagged by `<<ListboxSelect>>`. Using `<<ListboxSelect>>` is useless for binding to a letter key, however. It only will fire for mouse clicks and using the arrow keys to navigate the listbox.

You can bind to `<KeyPress>`. That binding will tell you what key was pressed, and in that binding you can change the widget's selection. You can get that information from `event.keysym`